# Can you access depedencies of depedencies with gradle?

Tags: gradle, dependency-management

Suppose that you have a Java project with Gradle for the build system, and you depend on library A. Furthermore, library A depends on library B. Can you call code(methods, classes, etc..) from library B?

If you can access the services of B, is there a way to prevent this? i.e. only direct depedents can access B code.

Comment: in current gradle version (6.6), you can declare dependency in A: api libraryB. Then libraryB will be available in your project. With only implementation libraryB, then libraryB will not be automatically available in your project. More information in https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#java_library_plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Suppose that you have a Java project with Gradle for the build system, and you depend on library A. Furthermore, library A depends on library B. Can you call code(methods, classes, etc..) from library B?

Yes, assuming it has been published with correct meta-data (either a Maven POM or Gradle Module file).

> If you can access the services of B, is there a way to prevent this? i.e. only direct depedents can access B code.

The dependencies of `A` (e.g. `B`) are called *transitive* dependencies, and you can disable the resolution of those in the [dependency declaration](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/ModuleDependency.html#setTransitive-boolean-) with `transitive = false`. However, `A` will likely break if you do that. Unless the meta-data for `A` is completely broken, it is normally not something you should do.